# Creating admin panel for android app using django

Tags: java, django, firebase, android-studio, e-commerce

I am building an eCommerce android app using java. I have used firebase as a backend for the android app.

This e-commerce app will contain all the necessary features for e-commerce platform such as-

```
1) Authentication
2) Product Browsing
3) Checkout

etc.
```

I want to use firebase for an authentication system, but for most frequently used features such as viewing products I want to use a separate backend system that is built on the top of Django.

I also want to handle the firebase database right from the Django admin dashboard. The business owner doesn't know how to deal with any coding he'll be working on a nice user interface i.e. our Django admin dashboard.

Can you help me figure out how to implement this kind of system and link everything together?